# Edit table row inline on click of edit in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I have a table where data is populating. Each row has an edit link. I want to edit only a particular row on click of edit link. Right now its' showing edit option for all the rows.

Also I want to show the text in a input box on click of edit.

Here is my code.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of backendData.report"  class="hover-highlight">

          <td class="benchmark_name">
             {{row.name}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{row.value}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{row.description}}
          </td>
          <td>
              <button *ngIf="enableEdit" (click)="enableEdit=false" class="btn page-secondary-action-btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              <button *ngIf="enableEdit" id="saveBtn" class="btn page-primary-action-btn" (click)="saveSegment()" type="submit">Save</button>
              <a class="table-row-action edit-action" *ngIf="!enableEdit" (click)="enableEdit = true">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil" uib-tooltip="Edit" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="left"></i>
        </a>
          </td>
          <td>

          </td>
        </tr>
```

My current output looks like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: I supouse you can simplifly, but this https://netbasal.com/keeping-it-simple-implementing-edit-in-place-in-angular-4fd92c4dfc70 is an amazzing article about this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution

html

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of backendData; index as i;"  class="hover-highlight">

          <td class="benchmark_name">
             {{row.name}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{row.value}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{row.description}}
          </td>
          <td>
              <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" (click)="enableEdit=false" class="btn page-secondary-action-btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              <button *ngIf="enableEdit && enableEditIndex == i" id="saveBtn" class="btn page-primary-action-btn" (click)="saveSegment()" type="submit">Save</button>
              <a href="#" class="table-row-action edit-action" *ngIf="!enableEdit" (click)="enableEditMethod($event, i)">
                edit
        </a>
          </td>
          <td>

          </td>
        </tr>
```

ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  enableEdit = false;
  enableEditIndex = null;
  backendData = [{
    "name": 'Target',
    "value": '100',
    "description": 'abc'
  },
  {
    "name": 'Size',
    "value": '20',
    "description": 'def'
  },
  {
    "name": 'Industry',
    "value": '40',
    "description": 'ghi'
  }]

  enableEditMethod(e, i) {
    this.enableEdit = true;
    this.enableEditIndex = i;
    console.log(i, e);
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Awesome..  This works. As I have asked in my main question how can I show the value and description in an editable box on click of edit button. And on click of save/cancel it should hide again. (On save of course it will call the backend API)

Comment: Hey Piyush... one more thing. On click of edit, it should show the buttons for that row and hide the edit link for that row only. But in this case onclick of edit link its showing save/cancel button for that row, but also hiding the edit link for other rows.

Comment: Checking... Thanks buddy.

Comment: Hi @piyushjain your stackblitz link is broken can you please fix it, it will be helpful for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @PiyushJain Hi https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wq8vru this link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an index in loop

Then create an array of enableEdit of length i.

Then on click event, write a function which takes a parameter index i.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set the "contenteditable" property of the row set to "true".
For example :

By default HTML keeps this to false.

You can get the current index of the table row using either by "trackBy" in *ngFor

```
*ngFor="let post of posts;trackBy:post?.id"
```

or you can use this keyword for the current index.

While saving or cancel just make the td's contenteditable to false.